# Unable to delete Access Role in RSA Archer

Tags: rsa-archer-grc

I am trying to delete a role which is corrupted during the upgrade process. Even after removing all the rights, I am not able to delete the role. Below is the error:
[image]

Version of Archer is 6.9.3.1.
Can anyone please help me with this ?
Thanks in Aadvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few users were assigned with the role manually. After removing the role from those users, I was able to delete the role.

Comment: @ouflak, Hey thanks for the changes